# Github pages не грузит сайт

Tags: github-pages

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему. Подключил проект к github pages, и при переходе по ссылке открывает страницу с названием проекта, а сам сайт не грузит. Что делать и как исправить? [image: Изображение данной ошибки]

KataRru/KataRru.github.io - название проекта по документации https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart

Comment: В настройке репозитория смотрели меню pages?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо переместить все файлы из папки dist в корень проекта, также необходимо в настройках проекта на github во вкладке pages выбрать ветку main

[image: pages]

Comment: Переместил файлы из dist в корень проекта и все заработало, спасибо большое! Но возник еще один вопрос. Папку "dist" не нужно добавлять в репозиторий проекта?